# Is there a find function in JavaScript that returns what your function returns and not the whole item when the value is truthy

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm

I want to return only the matched item, I solved this problem creating my own high order function, I want to solve this in a completely functional way.

Is there any similar javascript function that does what my function is doing? See the examples below, I wrote some Jest based examples to facilitate what I am expecting.

The function will try to `find` the value until is different than undefined. If this kind of function does not exist what you guys think of trying implementing it on JavaScript, maybe making a tc39 proposal? Anyone had the same problem as me before?

I know how the `Array.prototype.find` works and why it does not work when chained to get deep elements.

There are some conditions that I would like to meet:

1. Return what my function returns and not the whole item if it's truthy.
2. For performance reasons, when the value is found there is no need to keep looping in the array, in the example below I used the condition anything different from `undefined` to exit the `for` loop.
3. Follow the standard of the others high order functions such as `find`, `map`, `filter` and `reduce` like this: `fn(collection[i], index, collection)`.

```
const findItem = (collection, fn) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
    const item = fn(collection[i], i, collection)
    if (item !== undefined) return item
  }

  return undefined
}
```

```
let groups = [
  { items: [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }] },
  { items: [{ id: 3 }, { id: 4 }] },
]
```

```
var result = findItem(groups, group =>
  findItem(group.items, item => item.id === 4 ? item : undefined))
// works!
expect(result).toEqual(groups[1].items[1])
```

```
// Array.prototype.find
var result2 = groups.find(group =>
  group.items.find(item => item.id === 4 ? item : undefined))
// returns groups[1], don't work! And I know why it does not work.
expect(result2).toEqual(groups[1].items[1])
```

Comment: I don't think there's a built-in function that does this.

Comment: I just checked lodash, it doesn't have a function like this, either.

Comment: FYI the reason it doesn't work is because the callback to `find()` is supposed to return a boolean value.

Comment: Neither does underscore.js.

Comment: Even if any of them did have a similar function, they would almost certainly just check the truthiness of the return value, not whether it's `=== undefined`.

Comment: The `for` loop will continue until the value returned by the function is different than undefined, that means I got an 'explicit' return, we could also check truthiness and still return the value of the function just changing to `if (item) return item`.

Comment: @MarkMeyer yeah, I know.

Answer (score 0):

Probably horrible, but you could make use of a backdoor in the `reduce` function that would allow you to exit early on a match

```js
let groups = [
  { items: [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }] },
  { items: [{ id: 3 }, { id: 4 }] },
];
const item = groups.slice(0).reduce((val, g, i, arr) => {
 for (const item of g.items) {
   if (item.id === 4) {
     val = item;
     arr.splice(1); // exit
   }
 }
 return val;
}, null);
item && console.log(item);
```

*Note - use of `slice` is to ensure the original array is not mutated*

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, there is a condition I forgot to state in my question, I will add it now, the condition is that I want to avoid keep looping in the array when I find the matched value because it's just waste of performance and does not make sense. The solution is complex, not exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: @HugoNasciutti this will stop looping when you find the correct answer (hence the `arr.splice(1)` line). On the performance point, do you have any benchmarks you can back that up with? How large are the arrays? Just be wary you aren't micro optimising.... regardless, you asked if there was a way natively to do this, so I figured I'd at least give you an option.